# Discord.py Meme Command with cs and AIOHTTP

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command(aliases=['memes'])
async def meme(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Meme", description=None)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/wholesomememes/new.json?sort=hot') as r:
            res = await r.json()
            embed.set_image(url=res['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, content=None)
```

I found this block of code off a stackoverflow question I would really like to know how this works. I feel like it could improve my understanding of discord.py :>
So if you don't mind and have the time and knowledge, please answer! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this does is send a GET request to the given url, which itself returns JSON data. If you send the request over any browser you will see that you recieve data in JSON Format. If you use Firefox for example, it will automatically give you the option to inspect it as a JSON object. For better understanding you can then click your way down the Keys

```
['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url']
```

So you go under data -> children -> choose a random number -> data -> url
You will see the end result is a url string which directs you to a meme picture.

The final step in the code snippet is that it sends the url you yust got somewhere (im guessing into a discord chat)

Comment: how would you get the number of comments? because res['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['comments'] for me raises an error